# What causes "Invalid advise flags" run-time error in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

I have a Excel macro that generates a this error whenever it gets input of a specific format. Does anyone knows **in general** what an *advise flag* is OR where can I find information on this type of error? Thanks

> Runtime error -2147221503
>   (80040001): Automation error, Invalid
>   advise flags

Answer (score 1):

It's part of Microsoft's OLE component. See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.ole.interop._olecadvf.aspx)

This doesn't solve your problem, but maybe you can find more info there.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone pulling their hair out; this could also be a custom Error and unrelated to 'Invalid advise flags':

```
Err.Raise (vbObjectError + 1)
```

Note: vbObjectError =  **-** 2147221504